# Network.getNetworkId()

Tags: apex, community

I need to write a test class for a class

```
public static string getCurrentSiteURL() {

    String nwid = Network.getNetworkId();
    String servUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
    if (!String.isBlank(nwid)) {
        nwid = Network.getLoginUrl(nwid);
        nwid = nwid.replace(servURL + '/', '');
        nwid = nwid.replace(servURL, '');
        nwid = nwid.split('/')[0];
        servUrl+= '/' + nwid;
    }         

    return servUrl;
}
```

How can I set `nwid = Network.getNetworkId();`

Answer (score 2):

If you define a User, you can then use User.network.Id. See [this reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/Content/user_object.htm) for more on that. You might also find the code in the helper class in [Best Practices for Salesforce to Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practices_for_Salesforce_to_Salesforce) of use to you.

Comment: I tried creating an User . Added networkId filed .   Getting an Error: Compile Error: Invalid field networkId for SObject User

Comment: From the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf), Network is only available when a Community is defined for an Org. Did you use a Community User? NetworkId is also a reference field in the NetworkMember object that could be obtained with a schema describe call. You may need to enable SeeAllData in order to access it unless you either query a community user to use for testing or else define a Community in your test and I seriously doubt you want to do the latter.